# How can I parse just the latitude and longitude information from a JSON string in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, google-maps, json.net

I've looked everywhere and can't find a solution that works for me with this problem.

I'm using the Google Maps API and need to take an address, convert it to latitude/longitude, and then generate my map with those values.

I'm using NewtonSoft.Json to try and deserialize my string but am getting different errors for every method I try.

Here is how I'm accessing my JSON:

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW,%20Washington,%20DC%2020500&key=AIzaSyAKORLziVDRpaIlRs7NrPwGsye9NNn6Mdw");
```

Right now I'm only using a static address for debugging purposes, but will be switching to variables later.

[Here is the URL to see the JSON:](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW,%20Washington,%20DC%2020500&key=AIzaSyAKORLziVDRpaIlRs7NrPwGsye9NNn6Mdw)

I know that this is imported correctly because I'm using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("json "+json);` to check and debug.

I've also confirmed with https://jsonlint.com/ that it is valid JSON.

So now, I need to deserialize this String to grab

> ```
>         "location" : {
>            "lat" : 38.8976633,
>            "lng" : -77.03657389999999
> ```

and save them into variables for later access.

I would like to do this without making an entire class, but if that's what needs to be done I can manage.

Can anyone help me format the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` command to work for this?

Comment: Could you share the errors you're getting?

Comment: have you read the newtonsoft docs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to define c# classes to your json. It is not manual work. Copy all json to clipboard. Then go to Visual Studio, open create new .cs file with class, and then `Edit->Paster special->Paste JSON as Classes`. In your case it will be these classes

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Result[] results { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public Address_Components[] address_components { get; set; }
    public string formatted_address { get; set; }
    public Geometry geometry { get; set; }
    public string place_id { get; set; }
    public string[] types { get; set; }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public Bounds bounds { get; set; }
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public string location_type { get; set; }
    public Viewport viewport { get; set; }
}

public class Bounds
{
    public Northeast northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Northeast
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }
}

public class Viewport
{
    public Northeast1 northeast { get; set; }
    public Southwest1 southwest { get; set; }
}

public class Northeast1
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }
}

public class Southwest1
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lng { get; set; }
}

public class Address_Components
{
    public string long_name { get; set; }
    public string short_name { get; set; }
    public string[] types { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can desesrialize it based on this classes

```
 var webClient = new WebClient();
 var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW,%20Washington,%20DC%2020500&key=AIzaSyAKORLziVDRpaIlRs7NrPwGsye9NNn6Mdw");
 var parsedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
 var location = parsedObj.results?[0].geometry?.location;
 Console.WriteLine(location.lat);
 Console.WriteLine(location.lng);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use JSON.net to deserialize partial JSON fragments [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm) is an example to what you are trying to achieve, and this is the code for your case.

```
 var webClient = new WebClient();
 string json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW,%20Washington,%20DC%2020500&key=AIzaSyAKORLziVDRpaIlRs7NrPwGsye9NNn6Mdw");
 JObject jsonOb = JObject.Parse(json);
 double lat  = jsonOb["results"]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
 double lng  = jsonOb["results"]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be best to make an object to cast the JSON into. But you could use untyped objects.

```
var outputObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonString)
```

when you make an object for the convert to cast to, you do the following:

```
Type outputObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Type>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: Vote up, for the correct answer.. This is the easiest way to work with json objects

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
var webClient = new WebClient();
var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600%20Pennsylvania%20Ave%20NW,%20Washington,%20DC%2020500&key=AIzaSyAKORLziVDRpaIlRs7NrPwGsye9NNn6Mdw");
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
Console.WriteLine(obj.results[0].geometry.bounds.northeast.lat.Value);
```

Comment: I like this approach a lot, however I'm getting an error at `console.writeline` "An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code"